# Importing camera to position in negative value coordination question

Tags: camera

I have 2 different blender files, with the same object but different colours, one is light Green, and the other Yellow.

I have set up my camera angle in the light Green file, and then import the camera to my 2nd blender file. The camera is imported correctly, but I want to reverse the Location and Rotation values to match the angle of my light Green angle. ( Like the example I have attached ).

As shown in the example I have reversed the values in the rotation and location panel, and the camera is not situated as I was expecting.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure that this is what you want, but if you look the camera from above, you can easier see how to change the camera properties, to get what you want:

[image]